# C# DateTime Exception error

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, datatable

I have dates column within an excel which are 01.02.2016 format all the way through (and maybe changed to 01/02/2016 in the future) and for each row they are added to a data table in my backgroundworker.

Looping through each datatable row i grab the date column and try to change the date a few times to get the correct sqlite format to save to the database.

See below;

```
foreach datatablerow {

    //change dots to slashes 
    string dateString = Convert.ToString(rowData["Date"]).ToString().Replace(".", "/");

    //do DateTime C# Formatting..
    //This is causing the crash/exception
    DateTime _dateString = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
    //also have used & crahses as well
    //DateTime _dateString = DateTime.Parse(dateString);

    //Change agian to suit sqlite database entry - 2016/02/01
    string change_dateString = _dateString.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

    //Insert database data...

}
```

However, I get System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime errors on the transaction loop (even though on another computer the same transaction works using the above code...

When I console each date I can see thet it gets converted correctly to 01/02/2016 but the DateTime part crashes..

Comment: this problem is related to the date culture on the machine that you are using

Comment: As in the machines OS is corrupt?

Comment: are you developing web or desktop app?

Comment: WPF Desktop program..would it have something to do with 32x and 64x Bit computers??

Comment: No it doesn't have anything with 32x or 64x. Every machines runs an OS that has a default culture, like "en-US" or "en-UK". now each culture have different date format and currency and so on. when you force your app to store/read date in a format different than the culture on the machine you get this exception

Comment: `string newDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/2016").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: Rohit Convert.ToDateTime("01/02/2016").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); works but when I use Convert.ToDateTime(dateString).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); it crashes even through the string returns 01/02/2016 (after converting using replace())

Comment: @BENN1TH: Which Data Type is your DateString in your SQLite DB? And which Provider are you using?

Comment: It is TEXT but the issue is manipulating the date from excel to prepare it for sqlite injection..once the format is changed to yyyy-MM-dd it will work but the DateTime change is crashing it..

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the invariant culture ?

```
 DateTime yourdate= DateTime.ParseExact(rowData["Date"], "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: This is the better solution, because it's independent of `CultureInfo`. +1

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact("01.02.2016", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  & DateTime.ParseExact("01/02/2016", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); still crashed the program

Comment: The OP mentioned "01.02.2016 format", which is *not* "yyyy-MM-dd". InvariantCulture *may* not apply in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove this String manipulation. It's bad coding...

```
string dateString = Convert.ToString(rowData["Date"]).ToString();
```

<del>.Replace(".", "/")</del>;

---

### Update

There is a common misunderstanding of the `DateTime` Value in `Sqlite`.
Why?

Because `Sqlite` has no storage data type for `DateTime` values build in. By default `Sqlite` handles Date and Time Values like this, in his DataTypes:

- **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- **REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
- **INTEGER**
  as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

#### How to catch the Error

So the problem could be

- **A** : Casting the wrong DataType to String
- **B** : An other Date Format than `ISO8601` in your **TEXT** Colum(`["Date"]`)
- **C** : Other `Culture` Setting in your Connection String

Try some Code like this:

```
try
{
    string dateString = rowData["Date"].ToString();    
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    throw new System.Exception("Couldn't get Data from Row! Maybe wrong DataType?")
}    

DateTime dateValue;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue))
{
    // handle parse failure
    throw new System.Exception("Couldn't parse this String: " + dateString)
}
```

Comment: I removed the string manipulation still got exception following the above. Just checked the excel cells and all are 01.02.2016 date format no whitespace